# Bug with git show

Tags: git

As far as git show is concerned origin and upstream are different.

When I do

```
git remote -v
```

I get

> origin  git@git.corelogic.local:corelogic/reports.git (fetch)
>
> origin  git@git.corelogic.local:corelogic/reports.git (push)
>
> upstream        git@git.corelogic.local:corelogic/reports.git (fetch)
>
> upstream        git@git.corelogic.local:corelogic/reports.git (push)

When I do

```
git show remotes/upstream/develop:oracle/framework/Programs/Populate_Datamart.sql
```

I get the file on branch develop in the central repository @git.corelogic.local

When I do

```
git show remotes/origin/develop:oracle/framework/Programs/Populate_Datamart.sql
```

I get that file at an earlier commit.
It's different!

Comment: Did you `git fetch --all`?

Comment: Please be careful with your wording. It's _possible_, but unlikely, that you've found a bug in Git. The problem is probably with something you're doing, or a misunderstanding of the tool.

Answer (score 1):

Edit to add a key item (which I should have listed first, probably): Git does not know or care that the two URLs listed under the two remotes use the same URL.

`git remote` lists your *remotes*.  These can have little or nothing to do with what's actually in your repository.

`git show` shows objects from your repository.  These can have little or nothing to do with your list of remotes.

Running `git fetch origin` will, in general, have your Git contact another Git, using the remote name `origin` to get the URL.  It will then obtain, from that other Git, commits they have that you lack (for whatever reason—either you never had them, so now you do; or you convinced your Git to get rid of them, so now they're back).  Then, as its final bit of work, it will update the *remote-tracking names* that your Git uses to remember the other Git's branches.  For instance, your `origin/develop`—the full name is actually `refs/remotes/origin/develop` but you can leave off `refs/` or even `refs/remotes/` in most cases—will now remember what *their* Git said *their* `develop` was at the time you were talking to them.  (This may be out of date within seconds of dropping the conversation, depending on just how busy that other Git repository is.)

Running `git fetch upstream` will do the same thing except that your Git will call up the Git whose URL is listed for the remote name `upstream`, and will then update remote-tracking names of the form `upstream/*`, instead of `origin/*`.

*After* you do these two fetches—or `git fetch --all`, which says *fetch from all remotes*—*then* your remote-tracking names will have the hash IDs for appropriate commits that now exist in your own local repository.  Your `git show` can then show you those commits, or files within those commits.

Comment: In other words the origin and upstream are not just pointers they are complex objects with lots of content and whilst I had recently done a pull on upstream I had not recently done a pull on origin.

It seems that it is not a good idea to have both upstream and develop both pointing to the same place because then their consistency has to be maintained. In other words I should get rid of upstream.

Comment: In this particular case, yes, that seems wise. :-)